# How to prove an inequality involving second moments and inverse distribution functions

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions, quantile-function

I have recently encountered a problem requiring dealing with two inverse distribution functions simultaneously.

For a cumulative distribution function $\Psi$, the function $\Psi^{-1}:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
is defined by $\Psi^{-1}(t)=\inf\{ x\in\mathbb{R}:\Psi(x)>t\}$.
[Here is the original problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmiTq.png)

I have solved question (2-1). When I try to prove the inequality in (2-2), I need show that $E[F^{-1}(U)\cdot G^{-1}(U)]\geq E[X\cdot 
 Y]$. However, I have no idea what $F^{-1}(U)\cdot G^{-1}(U)$ is like and do not know how to deal with it. I think question (2-1) may be useful. This is all I have done. Any advice will be helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Compute $P(F^{-1}(U) > x, G^{-1}(U) > y)$. Use the fact that $\{F^{-1}(U) \leq x\} = \{U \leq F(x)\}$.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. Could you please be more specific how this could apply? It seems $E[F^{-1}(U)\cdot G^{-1}(U)]=\int_{0}^{+\infty}P\{F^{-1}(U)\cdot G^{-1}(U)>t\}dt$. But I  can not figure out how to convert this into a double integral. Maybe I have some misunderstanding about the random variable $F^{-1}(U)\cdot G^{-1}(U)$. Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: Use the formula you derived in part (i) with $F^{-1}(U)$ and $G^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks a lot!